# Nginx configuration for angular and magento

Tags: magento, nginx

I want to do nginx setup for handing two project with same domain.

Example domain: example.com

- Angular project should run with `example.com`
- magento2 project should run with `example.com/shop`

I tried the code below, but its not working.

```
location /shop {
    alias /var/www/www.example.com/shop/;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/
    autoindex on;
}
```

Can please someone help me to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use official NGINX configuration sample as provided [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/nginx.conf.sample).

Naturally, you will prefix all the Magento 2 locations with `/shop/`, for your specific case.

So you will end up with this kind of config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;

    location / {
        root /path/to/your/generated/angular/resources;
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
    }
    # Magento 2 directives start here...
    location ~* ^/shop/setup($|/) {
        # ...
    }
    # The rest of Magento 2 directives...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the following config to serve your Applications:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;

    location / {
        root /path/to/your/generated/angular/resources;
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
    }

    location /shop {
        root /path/to/shop/;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/;
    }
}
```

I'm not 100% sure if the shop route will work. Maybe you need to configure php to serve it. Therefore you can follow [this](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) official example.

If you want to serve also to `www.example.com` you can set `server_name *.example.com` ([docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)).